# How can I add results of a computing to a Dictionary in parallel in Julia?

Tags: dictionary, parallel-processing, julia

I would like to parallelize the computation of the function `solveZeros` for the different elements in S. The function are written below:

```
function solveZeros(S)
  """
  Solves for zeros of a linear equation for each element in S and returns 
  a dictionary with arguments k as keys and the solution as item 
  """
  results = Dict{}()
  for (a,b) in S
    solution = bisect(a, b)
    results[(a,b)] = solution
  end
  return results
end

function bisect(a,b)
  """
  Uses bisection to find the root of the linear function. a is the slope 
  and b the intercept 
  """ 
  low, high = 0, 100
  while (high - low) > 1E-2
    mid = low +  (high - low ) / 2
    if abs(linearEquation(a, b, mid)) < 1E-1
      return mid
    elseif  linearEquation(a, b, mid) > 0
      high = mid
    else
      low = mid
    end
  end
  return nothing
end

function linearEquation(a, b, x)
  return a * x + b
end

S = Array([(1., -10), (1., -20)])
```

Can somebody kindly explain how to parallelize the computation of the function `solveZeros`? This is a working example. In my actual computation, the functions `solveZero` and `bisect` and `linearEqauation` are drawn from different modules. How can I initialize these functions accordingly for parallel computation?

Comment: `is not defined` means you didn't `@everywhere` the definitions needed for the other processes

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks for your reply! Can you suggest a way to make the computation in the question work?

Comment: I would've just `@everywhere` the right definitions and used `pmap`.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I modified the question and included a working exmaple. Do you have an idea how to approach the problem?

Comment: Did you try what I said? `@everywhere` in front of `function bisect(a,b)` and `function linearEquation(a, b, x)`. Then you can make `function solveZeros(S)` be a `pmap` call instead of a `for` loop. Instead of pushing values into a Dictionary, have it return an array of pairs for `k=>v`, and the call `Dict` on that array. If there's not a solution tomorrow I'll write something up, but it's nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thank you very much for your reply! It worked well.